# Inject a iframe on a HTTPS web Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, https, google-chrome-extension

Well i'm actually developing a google chrome extension and i have some issue with the HTTPS web Page.

So basically the goal of my extension is to inject iframe on the web page by using the content script, this works great with the normal page (i mean HTTP)

But with the HTTPS (like facebook, gmail) my iframe seems to be not injected, i suppose for security ? Is there a possibilty to force the injection ?

EDIT: To give more information the HTTPS Page, seems to block the content Script, Weird...

Comment: Out of pure interest, why would you want to inject iframes into secure webpages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've just find the solution... It was absolutely ridiculous...

If my content script were'nt injected it was only because of the manifest.json.

Previous manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": 
[ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "css": ["css/xxx.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/xxx.js", "js/listener.js"],
--->      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
} ],
```

New one :

```
"content_scripts": 
[ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "css": ["css/xxx.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/xxx.js", "js/listener.js"],
--->      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
} ],
```

Hope it will help other guys in my situation ;)